# jquery Colorbox multiple iframes on a page

Tags: jquery, iframe, popup, colorbox

Using Colorbox plugin for opening wufoo form iframe in popup. I use 2 buttons, each has a separate iframe inside. Popup opens, but always generates the first iframe, even if I click 2nd button. What am I doing wrong in the code?

```js
$('.popup-form>a').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).colorbox({
    "inline": true,
    "href": ".wufoo-form iframe",
    "width": 500,
    "innerHeight": $(".wufoo-form iframe").height(),
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jackmoore/colorbox/master/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>


<div class="popup-form">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="wufoo-form">
      <iframe height="437" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%;border:none" src="https://questu.wufoo.eu/embed/z13q0b2m1vhb6m4/">
                <a href="https://questu.wufoo.com/forms/z13q0b2m1vhb6m4/">Fill out my Wufoo form!</a>
              </iframe>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="popup-form">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="wufoo-form">
      <iframe height="437" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%;border:none" src="https://questu.wufoo.eu/embed/zbixuek11o6qx8/">
                <a href="https://questu.wufoo.com/forms/zbixuek11o6qx8/">Fill out my Wufoo form!</a>
              </iframe>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Iframe src different, parent boxes are same. Just didn't want to use different ids for each block and create separate functions for each block with iframe.

============================================================================
Updated code. Found the solution, this on works:

```
$('.popup-form').each(function() {
$(this).colorbox({
  height: 600, 
  width: 800, 
  iframe: true, 
  href: $(this).find('iframe').attr("src")
}); });
```

Comment: i cant see any colorbox button in your code?

Comment: .popup-form>a is a colorbox button which gets it's Colorbox class="cboxElement" on click. I could use this code: $(".popup-form a").colorbox({
  "inline" : true,
  "href": ".wufoo-form iframe",
  "width": 500,
  "innerHeight": $(".wufoo-form iframe").height()
});   but I have multiple different buttons with different iframes